# Gelatin in SOME tablets

Tags: halal-haram

gnc tablets has a pack of 5-6 tablets and some of them has gelatin in it. Can i consume the one which doesn’t have gelatin in it or return them all?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So i got supplements with has 6 types. 2 of them are coated with gelatin. I wanted to ask can i take the other one or not?